# How to pause a video after a certain time? video.js

Tags: javascript, video.js

I've been messing with video.js whilst learning javascript but can't seem to figure out how to make the video pause after a certain time has passed.

```
myPlayer.play(function(){
    whereYouAt = myPlayer.currentTime();
    if (whereYouAt == 10) {
        myPlayer.pause();
    }
})
```

That is my pause code.

Comment: I think you need to wrap that in a setInterval() in order to check the time more often

Comment: @xiimoss http://jsfiddle.net/EdjxN/17/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the `currentTime` in the `timeupdate` event callback:

```
var pausetime = 2; // stop at 2 seconds

var myPlayer = videojs('example_video_1');

myPlayer.on('timeupdate', function(e) {
    if (myPlayer.currentTime() >= pausetime) {
        myPlayer.pause();
    }
});

myPlayer.play();
```

**JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EdjxN/17/**

Comment: After some some time how to replay it again. My criteria is after 3 seconds, the video has to be stopped. and need to display the alert popup. After 5 sec the video need to play the remaining. Is this possible?